# When you omit “that” from “so/that” do you need a comma?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Examples:

It was so cold the pond froze over.

Or

It was so cold, the pond froze over.

Answer (score -1):

People frequently omit [that] from sentences, but usually only when speaking.

In, speech, omitting that from sentences is fine, and many people would still understand you and is unimportant. In these cases, omitting the comma is fine, like this example:

> The heat was up so high [that] almost everyone took off their coats.

Comma's in this voice pattern and structure are not needed, so in your case a comma isn't needed.

The final sentence should be:

> It was so cold [that] the pond froze over.

However, when writing, most writers include [that] anyways.